# Delete Azure Data Factory pipeline after successful run

Tags: c#, azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory

Right now I have a WebAPI application that after receiving a request dynamically creates a specific pipeline in C# to do a specific task.

However, because the [number of pipelines and datasets is limited to 5000](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/azure-data-factory-limits.md), the application requests will eventually cause to reach this limit. I'm thinking about a way to automatically delete the pipeline and its datasets, but I'm not sure how. Manual deletion is out of the question, unfortunately.

Is there maybe a way for executing a "self-destruction" of a pipeline after completion? Or maybe trigger of removing old pipelines periodically?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to "self destruct". But you could simply write a simple time-triggered Azure Function to runs once a day and deletes old pipelines using the SDK?!

Answer (score 0):

No such mechanism to cleaning all the resources directly in ADF,however you could use [Azure Function Time Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer) to implement it in the schedule.Please refer to my thoughts:

1.Create time trigger azure function(for example triggered every day) to query pipeline runs with [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelineruns/querybyfactory) or SDK.

2.Loop the results and filter the `Status==Succeeded` and `runEnd< today` to get the pipeline name list

[image]

3.Delete them one by one by name list by using Delete API.(REST API:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/delete)

4.Deleting datasets is a little bit of trouble. Although you can get the pipeline name, the activities in the pipeline are not necessarily the same, resulting in different datasets.For example,if it is copy activity,you could get `referenceName` in `inputs` and `outputs` array.If it is feasible to clear all datasets and they will be re-created, you can easily use the [LIST DATASETS API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/datasets/listbyfactory) and kill them all.

[image]